# Jar file not recognised while running job

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, sax, jdom

I am new to the Hadoop framework. I am writing a Map reduce job in which I read a XML file and extract links between a predefined set of tags. For this, I am using XmlInputFormat to read the contents from file and JDOM for parsing the contents. I have included the necessary jar file (jdom-1.1.3.jar) in my classpath and the code compiles correctly. But when I run my program jar using hadoop, there is a NoClassDefFoundError thrown for the class JDOMException (org/jdom/JDOMException).

I restarted the daemons after adding the jdom jar in classpath, but the error persists. I am guessing the error is because the daemons are not picking up the new configuration.

Am I missing something here, or is there a better way to parse an XML file for a map reduce job?

Comment: This error is the typical one when JDOM is not in the classpath... I can't help you get JDOM in to the classpath, but, what I can tell you is that JDOM 2.0.5 has a number of performance improvements, and that if you are doing heavyweight map-reduces, you may want to investigate. Why are you on 1.1.3 anyway (essentially 8 years old)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But with JDOM 2.0.5 also, it is giving a similar error.

Comment: As I said, I can't help you get JDOM in **your** classpath... (which is why I posted a comment instead of an answer....). Your problem is your classpath management in your deployed environment. Using JDOM 2.0.5 will help you with other things though.... ;-)